# How to unload Nitgen eNBSP SDK library dll

Tags: java

When I re-deploy an application and try to use the nitgen library an error appears. I initialize it like this: `new NBioBSPJNI();`
The error that appears is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Windows\System32\NBioBSPJNI.dll already loaded in another classloader
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2456)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2649)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:827)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1871)
    at deployment.siapenweb.war//com.nitgen.SDK.BSP.NBioBSPJNI.<clinit>(NBioBSPJNI.java:15)
    at deployment.siapenweb.war//siapen.utilitarios.biometria.UtilBiometria.<init>(UtilBiometria.java:35)
    at deployment.siapenweb.war//siapen.bean.CadastrarBiometriaBean.registrarBiometria(CadastrarBiometriaBean.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

> NBioBSPJNI.dll already loaded in another classloader

So what has happened is that when your webapp was loaded the first time, its classloader has loaded the DLL.  When you then redeployed the app, a new classloader is created to load your new code. Loads `nitgen` from your WAR file ...  and ... it fails because the DLL is already loaded.

If the GC was able to collect the old classloader, that would trigger the JVM to unload the (old) DLL and you could then load the new version.  However:

- Redeploying an app is not necessarily going to trigger a garbage collection.
- Even if it did, the old classloader *could* still be reachable.  (Read about classloader leaks ...)

---

One possible solution *might* be to force a full garbage collection between undeploying the old version of the webapp and deploying the new version.  However, that wouldn't work if there is a classloader leak.  (And figuring out how to get the GC to run at the right time could be tricky.)

A more practical solution would be to remove the nitgen JAR and any dependent JARs, and put them into your web container's shared library directory.  That means that they will only be loaded once by a shared classloader, and the problem of unloading / reloading the DLL won't arise.